# R - Unable to replace unrecognized escape symbol "\&" in character string

Tags: r, regex, replace, symbols, gsub

I've a string with some special symbols, and unfortunately I can't get rid of them. My character string is the following:

```
"Food Science {\&} Nutrition"
```

I've tried several options, but I can't obtain just the `&` symbol. I always get this error when I use `gsub()` or `str_replace_all()`:

```
'\&' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""Food Science {\&"
```

If I have just the brackets it's fine, I can do:

```
gsub(pattern = "\\{",
     replacement = "",
     x = "{Food Science")

[1] "Food Science"
```

But in my case, if I remove the bracket, there is just `\&` left and I get the error. Any idea on how to proceed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps it helps to check the encoding where the string originates from... (e.g. a file)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Thanks to your hint, I found out I made a mistake. I copied the string from the `View()` function of RStudio. If I retrieve it with my code

`library(RefManageR)
refmanager_summary <- unlist(GetBibEntryWithDOI(doi = "10.1002/fsn3.119"))$journal`

I have the following string: **Food Science {\\&} Nutrition** and there are no mistakes and I can make the substitution. Should I delete this post? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single backslash in a string, but you need to double it when entered.   So this string will have the content you want:

```
"Food Science {\\&} Nutrition"
```

Some functions (most notably `print()`) will double it when they display it, so you'll see

```r
print("Food Science {\\&} Nutrition")
#> [1] "Food Science {\\&} Nutrition"
```

However, there really is just one backslash there, as `cat()` will show:

```r
cat("Food Science {\\&} Nutrition")
#> Food Science {\&} Nutrition
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I will leave the question for future references.